# What is the Noether charge associated with the the color $SU(3)$ symmetry of QCD?

Tags: conservation-laws, gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, noethers-theorem, yang-mills

A version of the Noether's theorem applies to local gauge symmetries. What is the Noether's charge associated with a non-abelian gauge symmetry such as the color $SU(3)$ and how is that derived? I want an expression for the color charge operator like we have an expression for the electric charge operator. Please see Eq. (9) and (11) of the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48305/noethers-first-theorem-and-classical-proof-of-electric-charge-conservation).

Comment: For local symmetries, one uses [Noether's second theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_second_theorem), while [Noether's first theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) is for global symmetries, cf. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/13881/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66092/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ gauge symmetry is a local symmetry, and therefore it is not Noether's first, but [Noether's second theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_second_theorem) that applies to it, which does not yield conserved quantities.

For $\mathrm{U}(1)$ gauge symmetries like the electromagnetic symmetry, there is also a *global* $\mathrm{U}(1)$ symmetry, and hence a conserved quantity. But the global symmetry associated to a non-Abelian gauge symmetry is just the *center* of the gauge group, which is discrete for $\mathrm{SU}(3)$, and hence there is no conserved quantity associated to it. This center symmetry has physical significance e.g. in models of confinement, see [this question and its answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/206030/50583).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the global symmetry associated to a gauge symmetry? (e.g. what it is, how to find it, does it always exist..)

Comment: Or why it‘s the center of SU(3) and not just a global SU(3)?

Comment: @Stephan Note that a non-Abelian gauge transformation acts as $A\mapsto gAg^{-1} + \mathrm{d}g$, so constant transformations that are not in the center still change the gauge field, and are therefore still gauge transformations between physically identical states. In this answer, by "global symmetry" I mean a symmetry that does not change the gauge field and therefore transforms between physically distinct states, since these are the symmetries to which one can meaningfully apply Noether's theorem.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! So for the case of U(1), the center of the group coincides with the group itself, so that's why we have the additional U(1)?