# Global Part of Non-Abelian Gauge Transformation

Tags: gauge-theory, noethers-theorem, yang-mills, classical-field-theory

I have a perhaps stupid question about Noether's theorem.

In Abelian gauge theory, say

$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+\bar{\Psi}(iD\!\!\!\!/-m)\Psi, \tag{1.0} $$

where $D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+iA_{\mu}$ is the covariant derivative, the equations of motion are

$$\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}=J^{\nu} \tag{1.1}$$

$$(iD\!\!\!\!/-m)\Psi=0 \tag{1.2} $$

where

$$J^{\mu}=\bar{\Psi}\gamma^{\mu}\Psi \tag{1.3} $$

is a conserved current,

$$\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}=0 \tag{1.4} $$

following (1.1).

In fact, the spinor current (1.3) is also the Noether current associated with a global $U(1)$ symmetry. One can check that the current (1.3) is indeed gauge invariant.

In nonabelian case, we consider the spinor-Yang-Mills theory

$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}\mathrm{Tr}(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu})+\bar{\Psi}(iD\!\!\!\!/-m)\Psi. \tag{2.0} $$

One finds the equations of motion

$$D_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}=J^{\nu} \tag{2.1} $$

$$(iD\!\!\!\!/-m)\Psi=0 \tag{2.2} $$

where

$$J^{\mu}=\sum_{a=1}^{N}\left(\bar{\Psi}\gamma^{\mu}T_{a}\Psi\right)T_{a} \tag{2.3} $$

is a Lie-algebra-valued spinor current, and $\left\{T_{a}\right\}_{a=1,\cdots,N}$ is the set of generators of the gauge group.

In this case, the current $J^{\mu}$ is "covariantly conserved",

$$D_{\mu}J^{\mu}=0 \tag{2.4} $$

because

$$D\star J=DD\star F=F\wedge\star F-\star F\wedge F=F^{a}\wedge\star F^{b}[T_{a},T_{b}]\equiv 0$$

where the last equality holds because $F^{a}\wedge\star F^{b}$ is an inner-product $\langle F^{a},F^{b}\rangle$, which is symmetric.

However, there should be no constant of motion (i.e. locally conserved charge) associated with the spinor current (2.3) because of the covariant derivative.

**On the other hand**, there still can be a global part of the gauge symmetry of (2.0). Considering a "global gauge transformation" acting on (2.0), by Noether's theorem of the global symmetry, one finds a locally conserved current

$$J^{\mu}=\sum_{a=1}^{N}\left(\bar{\Psi}\gamma^{\mu}T_{a}\Psi\right)T_{a} \tag{*} $$

which is identical to the spinor current (2.3).

***Why would Noether's theorem fail in such a case?***

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/430935/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thank you so much for your answer.